# pass only changed fields serialize() jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple forms on a page. Each of these forms has its own save button. I need to make it so that when you click on the save of any of the forms, all forms are saved. That's all I did, everything works for me and is saved.

In the save function, I am looking for all the forms that are in the block:

```
let $allForms = $('#post .details').find('form');
```

Then in the request I collect all the data using serialize() and save:

```
$.ajax({
  url: action,
  data: $allForms.serialize(),
  type: "POST"
```

There are no problems with this, everything works.

The problem is this. In serialize(), all fields from all forms are collected and then transferred. But conditionally, in each of the forms, I can change only one field, and in the request I would like to see only the changed fields of all forms.

How can I do that? Now I have all fields transferred, but it is necessary that only changed ones are transferred.

I'm trying to add a new class to all my changed fields, and then in saving, already proceed from this:

```
functions: {
  changeField: function (e) {
    $(e.currentTarget).addClass('changed');
  }
}

events: function() {
  this.$body.on('change', '#post .details form .field', this.functions.changeField.bind(this));
}
```

But this class is added only for fields with type input and textarea, why doesn't change work for fields with type select?

Comment: It should work for select. Add a `console.log()` statement to the function to see if it's being called.

Comment: Do the selects have `class="field"`?

Comment: @Barmar She doesn't even get called

Comment: @Barmar input and textarea is output to console.log(), select is not output

Comment: I would suggest posting a minimal working example that demonstrates the problem. Selects do respond to the change event, so there is more to the problem than what you have provided.